# After a crash, how does Firefox know what tabs I had open?

Tags: linux, firefox

I browse in Firefox and in a sudden my power goes off.
After booting the machine and opening the browser, Firefox knows my last session's tabs.
Is there any file that Firefox is constantly writing to?

Answer (score 0):

yes Firefox writes to a file every time you browse to a new address in any tab... but this has nothing to do with data recovery. When you boot up and open Firefox, it simply reads the file.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox any other browser that we use are using has the same process for last session recovery. In the above scenario Firefox will recover the last session from `sessionstore.js`.